# on form submit user session data is lost

Tags: forms, codeigniter, session

I am working on a codeigniter listing application, everything is working fine in the application but when I am submitting the listing form, the user session data is lost.

I am having: agentId in session, which is visible after login but after submitting it is not in the session data.

Code:

```
$agentId = $this->session->userdata('agentId');

       var_dump($this->session->userdata);
    die;
\\ This session showing all user data including agentId


    $data['p_title'] = $this->project_model->projectName().' :: Property : Add New Property';
    $data['Message'] = '';  
    $data['heading'] = 'Property: Add New Property';
    $data['pageName'] = 'property';

    $data['title'] = filter_value('title', '');
    $data['meta_decription'] = filter_value('meta_decription', '');
    $data['keywords'] = filter_value('keywords', '');
    $data['type'] = filter_value('type', '');
    $data['sub_type'] = filter_value('sub_type', '');
    //$data['sub_type1'] = filter_value('sub_type1', '');
    $data['bedrooms'] = filter_value('bedrooms', '');
    $data['kitchen'] = filter_value('kitchen', '');
    $data['parking'] = filter_value('parking', 'YES');
    $data['bathrooms'] = filter_value('bathrooms', '');
    $data['area'] = filter_value('area', '');
    $data['price'] = filter_value('price', '0.00');
    $data['location'] = filter_value('location', '');
    $data['city'] = filter_value('city', 82);
    $data['country'] = filter_value('country', 102);
    $data['details'] = filter_value('details', '');
    $data['featured'] = filter_value('featured', 'NO');

    $data['countries'] = $this->general_model->listCountries($data['country']);
    $data['cities'] = $this->general_model->listCities($data['country'], $data['city']);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Property title', 'trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE){
        $agentId = $this->session->userdata('agentId');
         var_dump($this->session->userdata);
        die;
\\ but here the agent id and rest of user session data is removed.
        $Date = getCurrentDate();
        $Time = getCurrentTime();
        $DbFieldsAry = array('agentId', 'title', 'meta_decription', 'keywords', 'type', 'sub_type', 'bedrooms', 'kitchen', 'parking', 'bathrooms', 'area', 'price', 'location', 'city', 'country', 'details', 'featured', 'date');
        $InfoAry = array($this->session->userdata('agentId'), $data['title'], $data['meta_decription'], $data['keywords'], $data['type'], $data['sub_type'], $data['bedrooms'], $data['kitchen'], $data['parking'], $data['bathrooms'], $data['area'], $data['price'], $data['location'], $data['city'], $data['country'], $data['details'], $data['featured'], $Date);             

        if($this->general_model->addInfo_Simple($DbFieldsAry, $InfoAry, 'tbl_properties_list')){                    
            $activityId = $this->general_model->getSingleValue($data['title'], 'title', 'property_id', 'tbl_properties_list');
            setMessage('success_message', 'New property added successfully. Add pictures to property.');
            redirect(base_url().'property/update/'.$activityId.'/0', 'refresh');
        }
        else{
            setMessage('error_message', 'Unable to perofrm this operation, please try again later!');
            redirect(base_url().'property/user_listing', 'refresh');    
        }

    }

    $data['allowed'] = true;
    $data['warning'] = '';

    if(!isSuperAdmin()){
        $total_properties = $this->general_model->getTotalDataSimple1('property_id','tbl_properties_list');
        if(allowed_properties() <= $total_properties){
            $data['allowed'] = false;
            $data['warning'] = '<br/>You have reached to maximum limit of your property upload listing.<br/>Click <a href="'.base_url().'payment">HERE</a> to change payment plan.<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>';
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('add_property', $data);
```

The first var_dump for session check shows all session data, but why is all the user session data lost after submitting?

Comment: Q: Did you do a [session_start()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)?

Comment: yes login is working fine with other pages like search, profile. but when i am adding new proprty its logging out after submit.

Comment: $this->form_validation->run(), is creating issue, this is clearing all the session data

Comment: Aha!  Q: So it's not the "submit" per se, but CI "form_validation", correct?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) dump your $session immediately before/after `set_rules()`.  2) dump $session before/after `form_validation`.  3) Try changing the rule.  Please consider changing your title from '`on form submit` to `on CI form_validation`.

Comment: PS: I don't see any "bug" in what you've shown so far.  I'd focus on your form_validation rules, and what happens immediately before/after form_validation "run".  I'd also change your title so it doesn't say "submit" - I don't think that's the culprit.

Comment: found the issue, havnt update the cookie domain in config file... btw thanks for the support. might help in future if i face any problems related to these suggestions. :)